# Live capturing from Unity-like application

Tags: camera, streaming

I need such thing for non-game application:

A city-like 3D scene, containing a few people. People walk, run, stand, ... May be cars also.

Around the scene some cameras are located. And I need them to live stream 2D views to my application. I do not want to capture screen, because I will use lots of such cameras simultaneously.

May be Unity has such feature or something else?

Comment: "stream 2D views to my application". What is your application? and what do you mean by streaming, is it over the network ? how should streaming work ?

Comment: I want to make something like CCTV cameras analysis. So I need them to "live-stream" the picture. City-like 3D scene I need for debugging, because I do not have enough cameras. I think that both applications will work on one machine. So I just need stream from one application to another.

Comment: Would using something like Twitch.tv work?  Can you capture the video in one go and then process that video afterward (rather than "live" streaming) ?  Rendering the scene from multiple cameras at the same time may not be feasible on your target hardware, especially if your scene is meant to be vaguely realistically detailed; you may need to generate a video for each camera one at a time and batch process after.

Comment: We need to know more about your other application. It's possible to either convert the game view into video or use it directly in your application, but we need more detail.

Comment: I do not need very detailed scene, so I think that it is possible. My application will analyse CCTV videos and find something on them.

Comment: May be I need another engine in fact.

Answer (score 0):

You can place cameras in the scene to cicling these cams and capture the video with a other program like Fraps, and saves of scripting time